# Convert 5-minute data points to 30-minute intervals by averaging the data points

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataset like this:

```
Timestamp                Index    Var1
19/03/2015  05:55:00       1        3      
19/03/2015  06:00:00       2        4
19/03/2015  06:05:00       3        6
19/03/2015  06:10:00       4        5
19/03/2015  06:15:00       5        7
19/03/2015  06:20:00       6        7
19/03/2015  06:25:00       7        4
```

The data points were collected at 5-minute intervals. Convert 5-minute data points to 30-minute intervals by averaging `Var1`. For example, the first data point for the 30-minute intervals will be the average of the 1st data point to the 6th data point (row 1 – 6) from the provided dataset of 5-minute intervals.

I tried using

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='30min')).mean()
```

Comment: Do you want to get 30-minute averages of the `Var1` column? What is the error that was raised? What are the dtypes of your dataframe?

Comment: Yes. That right I want to get average  of the VAR1 column. The datatypes I am using is timestamp, index, and int.

Comment: And the error message?

Comment: It doesnt give me error, perhaps it doesnt avg VAR1 column, instead it aggregating time stamp col

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We solve specific problems not open-ended requests.  Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), then provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Answer (score 0):

To start from the first timestamp instead of aligning to hours, you just need to specify `origin='start'`. (I found that in [the docs on `Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html).)

Also, averaging the `Index` column doesn't really make sense. It seems like you want to select only the `Var1` column.*

```
df.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='30min', origin='start')
    )['Var1'].mean()
```

Output:

```
Timestamp
2022-09-04 05:55:00    5.333333
2022-09-04 06:25:00    4.000000
Freq: 30T, Name: Var1, dtype: float64
```

---

* Or you could just as easily do something else with the `Index` column, for example, keep the first value from each group:

```
...
    ).agg({'Index': 'first', 'Var1': 'mean'})
```

```
                     Index      Var1
Timestamp                           
2022-09-04 05:55:00      1  5.333333
2022-09-04 06:25:00      7  4.000000
```